# Add custom markup to .NET Theme .skin file?

Tags: asp.net, themes, skin

I am new to .NET Themes. I would like to display different static HTML content in various places using Themes of my Web Application.

My first attempt was to use the ASP Literal control as follows:

In .aspx page:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" SkinID="HomeContentFooter"/>
```

and in my .skin file:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" SkinID="HomeContentFooter">
     <div>
          <!-- I hoped to put some custom static markup for each theme here -->
     </div>
</asp:Literal>
```

This produces the following error:

*The control type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal' cannot be themed.*

So is there another approach for this using themes?

Answer (score 0):

`Literal` control is rendered as plain text on your html, that is, when you have `<asp:Literal ID="id" runat="server">Hello World</asp:Literal>` you will get just **Hello World** on client. Since skin files are used for setting properties of elements and literal does not have style related properties or any properties or tags at all, it makes sense that it cannot be themed.

You can use `asp:Panel` instead, you customize it in your skin file and it will be rendered as `div`.

Comment: I have actually managed to solve my immediate issue using separate Master pages. However for posterity I tried using an asp:Panel as you describe, but it is not rendering the HTML from the skin file. (No compile errors this time though!)

Comment: That is weird, I've created .NET 4.5 web site. I have <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">Hello World!</asp:Panel> in my aspx, <asp:Panel runat="server" BackColor="SkyBlue" /> in my skin file and when I look at source html in browser, I got <div id="pnl" style="background-color:SkyBlue;">Hello World!</div>

Comment: Ah yes! But what I was hoping to do was to add some custom markup for the panel in the Skin File. I guess this it will not allow this.